# Why doesn't List.contain match substrings?

Tags: java

I have a program made where I add a +1 in the counter if the word matches the words I have in the list

For example if I have the word [OK, NICE] and I am looking at a word (the sentence is a split with a space).

In the split I don't want to put an option for commas and points, I just want a space like this now

```
private static int contWords(String line, List<String> list) {

String[] words= line.split(" ");
int cont = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    if (list.contains(words[i].toUpperCase())) {
        cont++;
    }
}
return cont;
}
```

This would be an example of words that don't add +1 to the counter and should

OK = true

OKEY= false

NICE. = false

NICE, = false

Comment: `List#contains` searches its elements for one that `equals` the argument. And `"OK".equals("OKEY")` is false.

Comment: "**OK**" contains in "**OK**ay" but not the other way around.

Comment: @Slaw yeah I know, but idk how to solve this

Comment: @PM77-1 so, there's other way to do it with contains?

Comment: If that what you need.

Comment: You're probably looking for `String#contains`, which means you'll have to loop manually over the `List` as well. However, I don't quite understand the desired inputs and outputs enough to give a confident answer.

Comment: Please disregard my comments. They are correct but irrelevant. @Slaw is right.

Comment: @Slaw for example in the parametre line I get the sentence "Okey, thanks" then I split the sentence in every blank space and I see if the word it's in the list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The problem

Here is the problem you are trying to solve:

- Take a list of target words
- A sentence
- Count number of occurrences of the target words in the words of the sentence

Suppose you are looking for 'OK' and 'NICE' in your sentence, and your sentence is "This is ok, nice work!", the occurances should be 2.

### Options

You have a few options, I am going to show you the way using [`Streams`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html)

### Solution

```
private static int countWords(String sentence, List<String> targets) {
    String[] words = sentence.split(" ");
    return (int) Stream.of(words)
            .map(String::toUpperCase)
            .filter(word -> targets.stream().anyMatch(word::contains))
            .count();
}
```

### How does it work?

Firstly, you take in a sentence, then split it into an array (You have done this already)

Then, we take the array, then use `map` to map every word to its uppercase form. This means that every word will now be in all caps.

Then, using `filter` we only keep the words that exist, as a substring, in the `target` list.

Then, we just return the count.

### More in depth?

I can go through what this statement means in more detail:

```
.filter(word -> targets.stream().anyMatch(word::contains))
```

`word -> ...` is a function that takes in a `word` and outputs a `boolean` value. This is useful because for each word, we want to know whether or not it is a substring of the targets.

Then, the function will compute `targets.stream().anyMatch(word::contains)` which goes through the target stream, and tells us if any of the words in it contain (as a substring) our word that we are filtering.

### NINJA EDIT:

In your original question, if the sentence was "This is Okey, nice work!" and the target list was `["OK", "OKEY"]`, it would have returned 2.

If this is the behaviour you want, you can change the method to:

```
private static int countWords(String sentence, List<String> targets) {
    String[] words = sentence.split(" ");
    return Stream.of(words)
            .map(String::toUpperCase)
            .map(word -> targets.stream().filter(word::contains).count())
            .reduce(0L, Long::sum)
            .intValue();
}
```

### NINJA-IER EDIT:

Based on the other question proposed in the comments, you can replace all matched words with `"***"` by doing the following:

```
private static String replaceWordsWithAsterisks(String sentence, List<String> targets) {
    String[] words = sentence.split(" ");
    List<String> processedWords = Stream.of(words)
            .map(word -> targets.stream().anyMatch(word.toUpperCase()::contains) ? "***" : word)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    return String.join(" ", processedWords);
}
```

Comment: The problem with this, I think, is that the OP wants to match `"NICE"` (from the `list`) to `"NICE."` or `"NICE,"` (from the split `line`). And `"NICE".contains("NICE.")` is false.

Comment: @Slaw I don't quite understand the comment? If the sentence is "OKEY OK", and the target is "OK", the count should be 2, right?

Comment: @Slaw Exactly but if in the list is the word OK should match with "OKEY"  "OKEY." and "OKE,"

Comment: @JClassic Exactly

Comment: @Lluis I think the solution is ok then? Can you try it and let me know if there is an issue

Comment: @JClassic Yeah, it worked! Thank u so much, just curious, if u want to change for example the words for "***" and the method returns and string, it's possible using Streams too?

Comment: @JClassic I ended up removing that part of my comment. However, using the approach you have you'll only ever find _one_ match per spit element from the sentence, due to your use of `anyMatch`. If that's okay, then I just don't understand the requirements and you should just ignore me.

Comment: @Slaw I had thought that was the intended behaviour. Of course you can use `targets.stream().filter(word::contains).count()` then used map instead of filter, then reduce.

Comment: @Lluis Not sure I understand your question?

Comment: My problem was if _`targets`_ contained both `"OK"` and `"OKEY"`, then if _`sentence`_ contained the word `"OK"` you'd get _two_ matches for _one_ word. Once I realized you were using `anyMatch` I figured it no longer mattered. But then your response, combined with OP's, made me think maybe OP _did_ want _two_ matches. But I'm honestly just getting confused.

Comment: @Slaw Interesting, I updated the answer to account for the other possibility

Comment: @JClassic If u have the sentence "This is ok, nice work!"  return "This is ***, *** work!"

Comment: Note, with your reduce option, you could use `mapToLong(word -> targets.stream().filter(word::contains).count()).sum()`.

Comment: @Lluis did you want to keep the comma? A simple String.replace should suffice if you do. EDIT: that would also mean that "Word okeyyyyyyyy" to be changed to "Word ***yyyyyyy"